# How do I find distribution function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

It is given following function and $p1=\frac{1}{4},p_2=\frac{1}{5},p_3=c,p_4=\frac{1}{2}$:

[image]

**a)** Determine $c$ such that this function is a probability-density function.

$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+c+\frac{1}{2}=1$

$c=\frac{1}{20}$

**b)** Give the distribution function $F(x)$ and finish the given sketch?

Can someone help me with **b)**? I think I should find indefinite integral, but not sure how excatly.

Comment: If F is the cumulative distribution function, $F(x)=P(X<x)$ it is an increasing staircase function.

Answer (score 1):

No integration is needed.  The distribution function is simply $$F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x],$$ and you already know that $$\Pr[X = x_i] = p_i, \quad i = 1, 2, 3, 4.$$  So you have for example $$F_X(x_2) = \Pr[X \le x_2] = p_1 + p_2.$$  What is $F_X(x_3)$?  What is $F_X(x)$ for some value $x$ between $x_2$ and $x_3$?

Comment: Can I write it like this: $F_X(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{4}, &x<x_1\\ \frac{9}{20},& x_1\leq x< x_2  \\ \frac{1}{2}, & x_2\leq x<x_3 \\ 1, & x_3\leq x<x_4   \end{cases} $

Comment: I would suggest modifying the limits, so that $F_X(x)=1$ for all $x>=x_3$ and $F_X(x)=0$ for all $x<x_1$

Comment: What about $\frac{1}{4}$ in that case? Which limit is for $\frac{1}{4}$?